# from django.db import utils ImportError: cannot import name utils error

Tags: python, scrapy

I have written a custom command for scrapy :

```
from pyes import *
from eScraperInterface import settings
from django.core.management import setup_environ
setup_environ(settings) 
from eScraperInterfaceApp.models import scrapedData
from eScraperInterfaceApp.eScraper_utils import eScraperUtils 
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 

class indexData():

    def __init__(self):
        self.utilsOBJ = eScraperUtils()
        conn = ES('127.0.0.1:9200')
        conn.create_index("scraped_data")

    def run(self):
        for i in scrapedData.objects.filter():
            data = {'productTitle':i.productTitle,'productSite':i.productSite,
                    'productURL':i.productURL,'productDesc':i.productDesc,
                    'productCategory':i.productCategory,'productSubCategory':i.productSubCategory,
                    'productMRP':i.productMRP,'productPrice':i.productPrice,'hasVariants':i.hasVariants,
                    'availability':i.availability,'currency':i.currency,'image_paths':i.image_paths}

            a = self.utilsOBJ.create_Index(data)
            print a
```

When i try to use scrapy shell command i got this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 4, in <module>
    execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 111, in execute
    cmds = _get_commands_dict(settings, inproject)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 37, in _get_commands_dict
    cmds.update(_get_commands_from_module(cmds_module, inproject))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 27, in _get_commands_from_module
    for cmd in _iter_command_classes(module):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 18, in _iter_command_classes
    for module in walk_modules(module_name):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 65, in walk_modules
    submod = __import__(fullpath, {}, {}, [''])
  File "/home/vaibhav/scrapyprog/comparison/eScraperInterface/eScraper/commands/indexData.py", line 10, in <module>
    from eScraperInterfaceApp.models import scrapedData
  File "/home/vaibhav/scrapyprog/comparison/eScraperInterface/eScraperInterfaceApp/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 92, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 24, in load_backend
    return import_module('.base', backend_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 30, in <module>
    from django.db import utils
ImportError: cannot import name utils
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you install python-mysqldb on your system?
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
or pip install mysqldb